# BIOS settings have been changed to Legacy Support but PC still boots through UEFI mode

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo (Ideapad 320) Windows 10 Laptop.
I had changed my BIOS setting to 'Legacy Support' and 'Legacy First'

[image: BIOS MENU]

This is an image uploaded from the internet which quite matches my BIOS Menu. After changing these settings and Optimise Default to Disabled - i.e.

[image: BIOS MENU]

I still get booted through UEFI mode. Can someone tell me what exactly is the problem I am facing ?Why does the PC Boots into UEFI still? Is it something to do with Legacy 'first'? I have gone through a lot of websites but have yet to find one with this problem listed.

Comment: You added Legacy Support and Legacy First, that doesn't mean that UEFI will NOT work... This seems like an A-B problem, what is the the underlying issue you are trying to correct?

Comment: I want to boot through Legacy.How do I go about that ? I have already changed my boot menu settings for Legacy and YET I get booted through UEFI. This is my issue

Comment: You need to re-partition the hard disk as MBR (or "DOS" mode), if it is GPT then the install will always be UEFI... In other words, you need to wipe your hard drive, change the partitioning to MBR and create a partition (a blank drive will be made GPT by Windows), then reinstall Windows. You can't just "switch" on the fly.

Comment: @acejavelin My entire HDD is partitioned using GPT.I am looking into 3rd party applications that promise to convert GPT to MBR without loosing data .I am skeptical to say the least.I wanted a confirmation if its possible .And is there anyway to bypass reinstalling Windows ? Also would there be a problem installing windows on an MBR drive.Some users on the internet say so.

Comment: Is there anyway to bypass *all this* ? I mean can I use the Legacy support features somehow with some tweaks with GPT partitioned drive ? I was originally dual booting which used EasyBCD which can be successfully used in Legacy mode.

Comment: I guess I am still trying to figure out what you are trying to "fix"... Are you wanting to setup dual boot again with ??? or something else? It just seems like your fix isn't going to fix anything. What is failing to work as you expect it to, does Windows not boot, does a different partition not boot, does some OS not install? Can you provide more details, because unless you have a pretty good reason to switch, there is zero advantage and several negatives to switching to legacy mode, but if you need to, then so be it.